# Query to list each child record in columns of a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I need expert help. I thought I knew SQL pretty well, at least up to this point. I'm working with SQL Server and need to build a query that lists each registered member and show each of the names of their guest(s) in separate columns instead of rows. Each member could have 0:N guests associated with each member. So,  Here are my tables:

Member Table: memberID (PK), FName, LName, ...

Guest Table:  GuestID (PK), FName, LastName, ...

Event Table: GuestID (PK), MemberID (PK),...

I am trying to build a query output like this:

MemberID | Member_FName | Member_LName | Guest1ID | Guest1_Fname | Guest2ID | Guest2_FName ...

**SAMPLE:**

```
Member Table
MemberID | FName | LName
001        Frank   Smith   
002        Mary    Jane
003        John    Henry

Guest Table
GuestID | FName | LName
101       Steve   Smith
102       Peter   Smith
103       Mike    Jane

Event Table
MemberID | GuestID
001        101
001        102
002        103
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
MemberID | FName | LName| GuestID1 | FName1 | LName1 |GuestID2 | FName2 | LName2
001        Frank   Smith  101        Steve    Smith   102        Peter    Smith
002        Mary    Jane   103        Mike     Jane
003        John    Henry
```

Please let me know if I need to include other information.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Next thing to google: "First Normal Form".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement both the `UNPIVOT` and then the `PIVOT` functions to get the results.  The `UNPIVOT` takes your columns and transforms the data into rows and the pivot takes the final result and turns it back into columns:

```
select MemberID,
  memberfirst,
  memberlast,
  isNull(GuestId_1, '') GuestId_1, 
  isNull(fname_1, '') fname_1, 
  isNull(lname_1, '') lname_1,
  isNull(GuestId_2, '') GuestId_2, 
  isNull(fname_2, '') fname_2, 
  isNull(lname_2, '') lname_2
from
(
  select MemberID,
    memberfirst,
    memberlast,
    col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select m.MemberID,
      m.fname MemberFirst,
      m.lname MemberLast,
      isNull(cast(g.GuestID as varchar(5)), '') GuestId,
      isNull(g.fname, '') fname,
      isNull(g.lname, '') lname,
      row_number() over(partition by m.parentid order by g.guestid) rn
    from member m
    left join Event r
      on m.parentid = r.memberid
    left join guest g
      on r.guestid = g.guestid
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (GuestId, fname, lname)
  ) unpiv
) src1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (GuestId_1, fname_1, lname_1,
              GuestId_2, fname_2, lname_2)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f592/24)

The above works great if you know the number of records ahead of time, but if not then you will want to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivotNull as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name +'_'+ cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select cast(row_number() over(partition by m.MemberID order by g.guestid) as varchar(50)) rn
                      from member m
                      left join Event r
                        on m.parentid = r.memberid
                      left join guest g
                        on r.guestid = g.guestid
                    ) t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('guest')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivotNull = STUFF((SELECT  ', IsNull(' 
                      + quotename(c.name +'_'+ cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))+', '''') as '+c.name +'_'+ cast(t.rn as varchar(10))
                    from
                    (
                      select cast(row_number() over(partition by m.MemberID order by g.guestid) as varchar(50)) rn
                      from member m
                      left join Event r
                        on m.parentid = r.memberid
                      left join guest g
                        on r.guestid = g.guestid
                    ) t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('guest')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select 
          MemberID,
          memberfirst,
          memberlast, '+@colsPivotNull+'
      from
      (
        select MemberID,
          memberfirst,
          memberlast,
          col+''_''+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
          value
        from 
        (
          select m.MemberID,
            m.fname MemberFirst,
            m.lname MemberLast,
            isNull(cast(g.GuestID as varchar(5)), '''') GuestId,
            isNull(g.fname, '''') fname,
            isNull(g.lname, '''') lname,
            row_number() over(partition by m.parentid order by g.guestid) rn
          from member m
          left join Event r
            on m.parentid = r.memberid
          left join guest g
            on r.guestid = g.guestid
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
         value
          for col in (GuestId, fname, lname)
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f592/21)

Both versions produce the same result:

```
| MemberID | MEMBERFIRST | MEMBERLAST | GUESTID_1 | FNAME_1 | LNAME_1 | GUESTID_2 | FNAME_2 | LNAME_2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |       Frank |      Smith |       101 |   Steve |   Smith |       102 |   Peter |   Smith |
|        2 |        Mary |       Jane |       103 |    Mike |    Jane |           |         |         |
|        3 |        John |      Henry |           |         |         |           |         |         |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'm almost there. On a side query of this project I'm working on, I was hoping you can look at this code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. The last 3 columns are suppose to show data but doesn't 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d8b/1/0

Comment: @RussellPeters you don't need to `UNPIVOT` that you only need to apply `PIVOT`. Do the contact details exist in another table?

Comment: Does the above query answer your question?  If so, then please consider accepting it as the answer via the checkmark to the left of it. It helps future visitors to the site know the answer that was chosen and you get site rep for it.

Comment: What do I need to edit on the query?  sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d8b/1/0

Comment: I see you added a new table but the Email column data is suppose to display data from the tbl_contactPreference's Descr field. I need to rename the query column heading to avoid confusion. Just suppose to show who opted in to each of the comm types. 
 
ParentID  | OptIn-Email  |  OptIn-Phone  |  OptIn-Mailing
001         Email                           Mailing

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question with the new details. That will probably be easier than going back and forth on comments.

Comment: Ok. Will do but the first example answered the questions. Just had a few bugs in it. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier to to make one column for the guests and have a comma separated list.

You could do that like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memberID, FName, LName, 
 STUFF((SELECT ', ' + FName + ' ' + LName + ' ('+GuestID+')'
  FROM Relationship R 
  JOIN Guest G ON R.GuestID = G.GuestID
  WHERE R.MemberID = Memeber.MemberID
  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS GuestList
FROM Member
```

That would look like this:

```
MemberID | FName | LName| GuestList
001        Frank   Smith  Steve Smith (101), Peter Smith (102)
002        Mary    Jane   Mike Jane (103)
003        John    Henry
```