# Dynamic Cols Pivot Rows but only some columns, not all

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm making a dynamic pivot table with a similar structure in the example below.

[Query to list each child record in columns of a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244930/query-to-list-each-child-record-in-columns-of-a-parent)

EXCEPT, all the examples I seem to find, when building the list of dynamics columns for the pivot, they all use "quotename" to get all columns in the table, while I only want a handful for my output.

```
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                  + quotename(c.name +'_'+ cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                from
                (
                  select cast(row_number() over(partition by m.MemberID order by g.guestid) as varchar(50)) rn
                  from member m
                  left join guest g
                    on m.guestid = g.guestid
                ) t
                cross apply sys.columns as C
               where C.object_id = object_id('guest')
               group by c.name, t.rn
               order by t.rn
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Wondering if anyone can help with the syntax. In the above example, instead of getting First name and Last Name, hypothetically, I only want Last Name. How would that look?

I'm just looking at how to replace the quotename properly, I believe I have the rest running properly.

**SAMPLE:**

```
Member Table
MemberID | FName | LName
001        Frank   Smith   
002        Mary    Jane
003        John    Henry

Guest Table
GuestID | FName | LName | MemberId
101       Steve   Smith | 001
102       Peter   Smith | 001
103       Mike    Jane  | 002
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
MemberID | FName | LName| GuestID1 | LName1 |GuestID2 | LName2
001        Frank   Smith  101        Smith   102        Smith
002        Mary    Jane   103        Jane
003        John    Henry
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you know the columns (and their names) that you want ahead of time, why not use a regular `PIVOT`?

Comment: I know the column names (like FName) but it is a 0 to many relationship between Member and Guest such that I have a dynamic number of columns for the pivot if that makes sense... Like I need LName1, LName2, ... LName^n I just don't want all the columns from the Guest table.

Answer (score 1):

Key point is that we need to use `row_number` window function to make a row number and then use condition aggregate function to make it.

```
SELECT MemberID,FName,LName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN GuestID END) GuestID1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN g_LName END) LName1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN GuestID END) GuestID2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN g_LName END) LName2
FROM (
    SELECT m.MemberID,
           m.FName,
           m.LName,
           GuestID,
           g.LName g_LName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.MemberID ORDER BY GuestID) rn
    FROM Member m LEFT JOIN Guest g
    ON m.MemberId = g.MemberId
) t1
GROUP BY MemberID,FName,LName
```

if there might be multiple `LName` (more than 2) and you want to use Dynamic pivot you can try the below code, but that might be a little complex.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ', MAX(CASE WHEN rn = '+ CAST(t1.cnt AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' THEN GuestID END)' + ' as '''+CONCAT(name,t1.cnt)+''''
            FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM Guest GROUP BY MemberId) t1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'GuestID' name UNION ALL SELECT 'LName') t2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT MemberID,FName,LName, ' + @cols + '  
FROM (
    SELECT m.MemberID,
           m.FName,
           m.LName,
           GuestID,
           g.LName g_LName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.MemberID ORDER BY GuestID) rn
    FROM Member m LEFT JOIN Guest g
    ON m.MemberId = g.MemberId
) t1
GROUP BY MemberID,FName,LName '
execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=dd4c94e1ce2a41614ac3e29197e416ba)